# How do I configure Mail to download my messages via IMAP/Gmail?

Tags: gmail, imap, apple-mail, osx-yosemite

I've configured Mail to access Gmail via IMAP. I've also configured Gmail, in it's settings, to limit each IMAP folder to only download 1000 of each folder. The problem is that I have a folder that has less than 1000 messages that has only downloaded. The weird thing is when I go to get account info (right-click on the account in the left-hand pane that displays all your accounts and folders), it shows that folder as having 0 messages.

I end up having to go to Gmail to check messages in that folder.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image: My screenshot]

Note how I've highlighted the `Web Accounts` folder in the background and how it displays seven messages but that the Account Info pane shows 0 messages.

Answer (score 0):

Re-sync the account by clicking mailbox, then sync Personal.